# Scala/Java - Inserting BSON to DB2 with prepared statement

Tags: java, scala, db2, bson

I am currently trying to write in Scala a code which write a JSON string into DB2, where the DB2 column has the type BSON.

I have a JSON String, lets say it is the following json string {"a":"Value-1","b":"Value-2"}. This information in combination with other values I want to write into DB2 with a prepared statement (BATCH-Insert). However I am not able currently to achieve this, I receive an error when I use the batch method. By using the normal executeUpdate method from prepared statement everything is working well. However, the speed is not satisfying.

Below you can find parts of the code/pseudo-code:

```
val query = "INSERT INTO Table (A, B, C) VALUES (?, ?, SYSTOOLS.JSON2BSON(?))"
val aValue = "Value-1"
val bValue = "Value-2"
val cValue = {"a":"Value-1","b":"Value-2"}

val db2Connection = connect-to-db2
var ps= db2Connection.prepareStatement(query)

ps.setString(1, aValue)
ps.setString(2, bValue)
ps.setString(3, cValue)

// The following two lines are not working with the code above.
// However by replacing this two lines with the third line everything works without any problem.
ps.addBatch() 
ps.executeBatch()
ps.executeUpdate()
```

If there exists an option without any additional libraries I would be happy to hear that, when not I am taking as option-2 also in consideration of using an external library for that code.

Comment: Would you please provide the error message(s), too?

Comment: Sorry for not adding it. Here is the Error code: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n312.html

Comment: What version of Db2 and platform are you using? It seems Db2 z/OS V10?

Comment: No we have 12.1.5 FL502

Comment: No one an idea?